# media queries: composing NOT with OR

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to write a media query that matches one of two ranges and then checks if the statements are false. This is to be able to compose [custom media queries](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#custom-mq) and execute behavior if neither matches. An example query would look like this:

```
/**
 * Intended behavior would be:
 * !((320px <= width <= 800px) || width <= 320px)
 */
@media not all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 800px), (max-width: 320px) {}
```

But unfortunately this query doesn't match anything; though using the statements separately does work. I'm curious what the above query translates to (and why), and how I can correctly compose NOT with OR in CSS media queries. Thanks!

**edit**: I am specifically looking for a way to combine 2 predefined media queries. Editing the queries themselves is not allowed. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 800px) {}
```

The goal is to mix and match [custom media queries](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#custom-mq). An answer that it's not possible is also an acceptable answer.

### See Also

- [W3 custom media query specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#custom-mq)
- [css-tricks logic in media queries](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be `!((320px <= width <= 800px) OR width <= 320px)` => `!(320px <= width AND width <= 800px) AND !(width <= 320px)` => `(!(320px <= width) OR !(width <= 800px)) AND (width > 320px)` => `((width < 320px) OR (width > 800px)) AND (width > 320px)` => `((width < 320px) AND (width > 320px)) OR ((width > 800px) AND (width > 320px))`, that is formally media query should look like

```
@media (max-width: 319.9999px) and (min-width: 320.0001px),
       (min-width: 800.0001px) and (min-width: 320.0001px) {}
```

PS. In this particular case the query may be reduced to just `(width > 800px)` => `!(width <= 800px)`:

```
@media not all and (max-width: 800px) {}
```